# ggplot2: Using formular in aes mapping

Tags: r, ggplot2

With data iris I want to the color of point of setosa specie different to other species. The command works with != operator but =operator does not.

I have two color with:

```
ggplot(iris)+ geom_point(aes(x=Sepal.Length,y=Petal.Length,**color=Species!="setosa"**))
```

I have only one color:

```
ggplot(iris)+ geom_point(aes(x=Sepal.Length,y=Petal.Length,**color=Species="setosa"**))
```

Comment: Try "==" rather than "=".  See the help pages at ?'=='

Comment: Thanks to @TonyLadson!

Answer (score 0):

did you tried using == instead of =, becuase != for sure returns a boolean, but = alone is changing the value of Species to setosa and then asigning setosa to color. you can double check by doing it outside ggplot

Comment: Thanks to @ShailynOrtiz, especially your explaination about the assignement with = oprerator.

Comment: Awesome, glad it was of help, could you mark this question? @TranQuyPhi